# compilation issues with pass-through function calls using generics

Tags: typescript, generics

In widget.ts I have the following:

```
  use_widget<T>(msg: () => T): T | undefined;
  use_widget<T>(msg: T): T;
  use_widget<T>(msg: T | (() => T)): T | undefined {
    if (someCodition()) {
       return msg instanceof Function ? undefined : msg;
    }
    return msg instanceof Function ? msg() : msg;
  }
```

Essentially, you can pass in any data type and that data will be returned in a type safe manner.  The one exception to this is if you pass in a function, in which case the return value of the function is returned, unless `someCondition()` is not met in which case the function is not executed and undefined is returned.  This all works happily for direct users of widget.ts.

Now, I also have a widget controller class which is used to handle one or more widgets, but there is also a default widget as well.  For specific widgets, the API is, e.g. `getWidet(widgetId).use_widget(data)`.  However for default widget use, I want to drop the requirement to call `getWidget()` first and use this code in widget_controller.ts instead to wrap the underlying call to `use_widget`:

```
export function use_widget<T>(msg: () => T): T | undefined;
export function use_widget<T>(msg: T): T;
export function use_widget<T>(msg: T | (() => T)): T | undefined {
  return getWidget("default").use_widget(msg);
}
```

Thus allowing the caller to simply write `use_widget(data)` when the default widget is needed (e.g. `getWidget()` is not required for the default case).  However the compiler is complaining on the line with `return getWidget("default").use_widget(msg);` with:

```
 Type 'T | (() => T)' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.
  Type '() => T' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    '() => T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
```

Can anyone explain what this means, why this is happening and how I can rework my API to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, which is to coerce the generic to a more specific type before passing through.  E.g.

```
export function use_widget<T>(msg: () => T): T | undefined;
export function use_widget<T>(msg: T): T;
export function use_widget<T>(msg: T | (() => T)): T | undefined {
  if (msg instance of Function) {
      return getWidget("default").use_widget(msg);
  }
  return getWidget("default").use_widget(msg);
}
```

This keeps the compiler happy and my type-safe tests happy too.  Why this works make a little sense to me, but I'd love a deeper explanation if anyone has one.  The solution (or workaround?) makes for odd code to read.